# {!! Form::open(['url' => 'home',files =>true]) !!} both url and file upload do not work together in form

Tags: php, laravel

I want the user to upload an image and come back to the same page ,but I can only have one thing ,either the url or the file

This the line of code I that can't figure out

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'home',files =>true]) !!}
```

This is the whole class for home.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
    @include('flash::message')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            {!! Form::open(['url' => 'home',files =>true]) !!}
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Add a new status</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label>Write a new status</label>
                       <textarea class="form-control" name="status-text" id="status-text"></textarea>

                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer clearfix">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6=">
                            <label for="file upload" class="custom-file-upload">

                                <i class="fa fa-image"></i>
                            <input id="file-upload" name="status_image_upload"  type="file"/>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6=">

                            <button class="btn btn-info pull-right btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add status</button>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}

            @foreach($top_15_posts as $status)
                {!!
                 view('layouts.app-internal.user-status-layout',[
                 'status' => $status,
                 'user' => \App\Eloquent\User::find($status->user_id),
                 'comments' => \App\Eloquent\StatusComments::where('status_id',$status->id)->orderBy('id','DESC')->get(),
                  'comment_count' => \App\Eloquent\StatusComments::where('status_id',$status->id)->count(),
                  'like_count' => \App\Eloquent\StatusLikes::where('status_id',$status->id)->count()

                 ])
                 !!}
                @endforeach

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Image of Error:
[image: Error]

Comment: The error is not coming from the shared code. It says "undefined index 'overlay'" but no overlay text anywhere.

Comment: I know when I take out `files =>true`from `{!! Form::open(['url' => 'home',files =>true]) !!}` I don't get any errors ,so it's coming from there and vice versa when I take out `'url' => 'home'`

Comment: Actually there's an error in that line in that `files` is not quoted, which probably triggers another error when trying to display the error messages. No error messages no other error.

Comment: I still get the same error even if with the files quoted :/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a cache error, try run:

```
php artisan view:clear
```

With that you avoid that you load your last changes in your views

Comment: No that didn't help :/

Comment: where? ,I think I have that line at the top of the class

Comment: I see what you meant , I took out `@include('flash::message')` and it worked!

Comment: yes, the problem is in views/vendor/flash/message.blade.php file, update your question and share the code of this file. if you see the ErrorException, says it does not find an index on some variable you're using

Answer (score 0):

It was simple mistake ,I simple had take out `@include('flash::message')` at the start of the home.blade.php class .